# For testing purposes, is there a way to "limit" how much I/O requests can be made at the same time on Linux? Or for one specific application

Tags: debian, disk, swap, freeze

This is a tough one, I don't know how to call what's happening, it seems to be something related to "intensive disk activity causes multi-threaded application to lock up".
Or "I/O disk lockups when there's heavy CPU usage".

I'm having I/O Disk problems in Debian Buster. (MX Linux) It's so weird because I don't even know how to describe the issue, is difficult searching for solutions when you don't know what exactly to search.
It seems like there are other people using Debian complaining about severe I/O problems as well. (for years too)
Something is "locking up" the entire I/O system.

I don't suffer these problems in Manjaro, so it seems to be an issue with Debian itself.
Tried different vm.dirty_xx value combinations, high, low, high and low swappiness, all combinations, no difference. Tried playing around with ionice -c 2 command, no difference.

In my case, it's when I try to load Cities Skylines, a C#/DotNet application that is having issues (DotNet games will claim all your memory and swap space regardless of the amount you have)
Screenshots with more detail for context:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xfZq.jpg
It would be nice if someone knew of command-line launch parameters that I could use with C# applications in order to make more tests, or to somehow limit the amount of disk threads it needs. The disk seems to be overwhelmed with requests, it looks like that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! It's hard to understand what precisely is your problem. I understand that your application freezes due to high disk IO, and this doesn't happen with Manjaro. Did you do the tests on the same computer? Did you run commands like `vmstat`, `iostat` or `top` to measure the system? Is only your application frozen or is the system as a whole unresponsive, i.e. what happens when you open a terminal window and run some commands - does that feel slow?

Comment: To answer the question in the title, yes. One way is using CGroups. Here is a random tutorial I found: https://andrestc.com/post/cgroups-io/. Official documentation at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html, and the IO section of official documentation is at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#io.

Comment: @berndbausch Did you see the screenshots I posted above? There are two terminals monitoring stuff in real time. Although I was not using vmstat, iostat. What are the commands for these? For a watchdog that updates each 2 or 3 seconds. (to not overwhelm the system even more I guess

Comment: Thanks I will look into that. My low reputation prevents from posting comments, but I think it allows me commenting in my own initial post, so at least there's that.

Comment: No, I didn't look at the images. You run vmstat like this: `vmstat 2 100`, which means to display VM measurements every two seconds, and hundred times in total. `iostat` works the same; you can also run `iostat` on a subset of your storage devices. `top` is usually run without parameters.

Comment: To sum it up: in the screeshots you will notice two "symptons": swap file does not get populated (or very very slowly...) and there are no "dirty" files in disk cache left behind. Rising vm.dirty_xx values does not bring changes to that "dirty" monitor whatsoever. Another sympton: sudo swapoff --all results in the swapfile being VERY SLOWLY depopulated. Not even my older laptop with bad blocks was that slow. Took around 5 minutes to empty Swapfile that had 800 MB of data on it. It's BAD.

Comment: Well, personally I don't know the algorithms that the kernel uses to drain swap or the buffer cache, so I can't comment on those.

Comment: My account was blocked from posting answers, exactly for the reason that I could not post comments (therefore having to write using answers) So now basically I can't comment on other people's answers and I can reply answers. Seems to me rather counter productive how this site is designed. Shouldn't comments come first? Anyway...

Comment: If you want to add information, you can edit your question.

Comment: `ulimit` can restrict memory usage.

Comment: I've created a new question, after discovering by accident that the same "system unresponsiveness" issue doesn't happen in Manjaro, it happens only in Debian, so it's not hardware, it's software.

Comment: The application I need to run is a game made in C#, meaning it has automatic garbage collector and it will max out RAM usage when 1st loaded. Even using "memory minimum low reserve" parameters or other methods to limit memory, the application will still claim all memory, leaving me with less than 100MB free RAM, which in turn activates the OOM killer procedure and triggers disk swapping. I'm just trying to find out why it works flawlessly in Manjaro and doesn't work in Debian. I can't rely on Manjaro for long term usage unfortunately, prefer Debian very much, apart from this specific issue.

Comment: It seems to be something related directly to I/O itself, because running the command Swapoff to flush swapfile also takes ages, even when less than 1 GB swap is occupied. Running the DD command to create an empty file on disk also takes ages. (this on Debian only... I can perform the same operations rebooting into Manjaro without hassle...)